# How to connect theese two ansible playbooks that solve a problem connected to JIRA automatization with his REST API

Tags: ansible, yaml, jira

The problem I am trying to solve there is to add users to JIRA using the JIRA REST API. the line I want to substitute in the **createUser.yml** file is the following

```
 loop: "{{ users }}")
```

and I want to substitute this with the list formed by the users described as JSON files (continue to read for the details on how the users and the list are implemented)
here I post you the
**createUser.yml** file

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create Jira Project
      uri:
        url: "{{ jira_url }}/rest/api/2/project"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ jira_username }}"
        password: "{{ jira_password }}"
        return_content: yes
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: 'application/json'
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
        body: "{ 'key': '{{ app_code + kapp }}',
                 'name': '{{ project_name }}',
                 'projectTypeKey': 'software',
                 'projectTemplateKey': 'com.example.plugins.tutorial.my-project-template:my-project-template',
                 'description': 'Project created using Ansible playbook',
                 'lead': '{{ project_lead }}',
                 'assigneeType': 'PROJECT_LEAD',
                 }"
        status_code: 201
      register: result
      tags:
        - project
    - name: Project Creation Details
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.json }}"
    - name: Add user
      uri:
        url: "{{ jira_url }}/rest/api/2/user?groupname=jira-software-users"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ jira_username }}"
        password: "{{ jira_password }}"
        return_content: yes
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: 'application/json'
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
        body: '{ "name": "{{ item }}" }'
      register: userResult
       loop: "{{ users }}"
      tags:
        - adduser

    - name: User details
      debug:
        msg: "{{ userResult.json }}"
```

This is the main idea behind the algorithm implemented, basically to have a list of JSON users and to loop it and to add each user iteratively with the JIRA API.

For modeling the users I have used this convention, creating for each user a YAML file. Example:
**jsmith.yml**

```
jsmith:
  project_role: administrators
  full_name: John Smith
  email: johnsmith@mail.com
```

Other example:
**pmorrison.yml**

```
pmorrison:
  project_role: developer
  full_name: Paul Morrison
  email: paulmorrison@mail.com
```

I also use this file:
**playbook.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        dir: user.d
        name: users
    - debug:
        var: users
 - set_fact:
        users_list: "{{ users_list|d([]) +
                        [{'username': item.0}|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ users.keys()|list }}"
        - "{{ users.values()|list }}"
 - debug:
        var: users_list
```

this other file **playbook.yml** file gives this result, that is the list of users as JSON files I want:

```
    "users_list": [
        {
            "email": "johnsmith@mail.com",
            "full_name": "John Smith",
            "project_role": "administrators",
            "username": "jsmith"
        },
        {
            "email": "paulmorrison@mail.com",
            "full_name": "Paul Morrison",
            "project_role": "developer",
            "username": "pmorrison"
        }
    ]
```

The main problem I want to solve is to have the users_list in the playbook.yml looped instead of the "users" list that is present in the **createUser.yml**

I have tried this solution by modifying the **createProject.yml** file inserting into it the code of the playbook.yml file, so I don't use anymore a **playbook.yml** file anymore but only a **createProject.yml** file that incorporates its logic, but it doesn't work:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    -users.d/pmorrison.yml
    -users.d/jsmith.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create Jira Project
      uri:
        url: "{{ jira_url }}/rest/api/2/project"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ jira_username }}"
        password: "{{ jira_password }}"
        return_content: yes
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: 'application/json'
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
        body: "{ 'key': '{{ app_code + kapp }}',
                 'name': '{{ project_name }}',
                 'projectTypeKey': 'software',
                 'projectTemplateKey': 'com.example.plugins.tutorial.my-project-template:my-project-template',
                 'description': 'Project created using Ansible playbook',
                 'lead': '{{ project_lead }}',
                 'assigneeType': 'PROJECT_LEAD',
                 }"
        status_code: 201
      register: result
      tags:
        - project
    - name: Project Creation Details
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.json }}"
    - include_vars:
        dir: user.d
        name: users
    - debug:
        var: users
    - set_fact:
        users_list: "{{ users_list|d([]) +
                        [{'username': item.0}|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ users.keys()|list }}"
        - "{{ users.values()|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: users_list

    - name: Add user
      uri:
        url: "{{ jira_url }}/rest/api/2/user?groupname=jira-software-users"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ jira_username }}"
        password: "{{ jira_password }}"
        return_content: yes
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Accept: 'application/json'
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
        body: '{  "{{ item }}" }'
      register: userResult
```

gives the error:

```
ERROR! vars file -users.d/pmorrison.yml -users.d/jsmith.yml was not found
Could not find file on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
```

I suspect there is an importation error (can you please confirm?)and can you tell me if the way I am structuring the logic of solving the problem is right and how to proceed to have a better design of the final solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's an indentation error. Write as follow, will solve

```
- users.d/pmorrison.yml
```